# How to add new data from array of string to array of object sequentially?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have array of object:

```
originalData = [
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 6
  }
]
```

And I have array of string:

```
newData = ['1','2','3']
```

How do I push `newData` to `originalData` sequentially?

Expected result should be like so:

```
originalData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "color":'1'
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "color":'2'
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "color":'3'
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "color":'1'
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "color":'2'
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "color":'3'
  }
]
```

Here's my workaround:

```
originalData.forEach(function (object,i) {
    object.color = newData[i]
});
```

Comment: What is wrong with your "workaround"?

Comment: @JuanMendes, Because the workaround would only set **color** to the first 3 members of the `originalData`. The rest members would have the **color** set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable `j` and reset it over time.

```
var j = 0;
originalData.forEach(function (object,i) {
    object.color = newData[j];
    j += 1;
    if(j > newData.length)
        j = 0;
});
```

Comment: What's different between this and what the OP posted?

Answer (score 0):

Reset the counter dynamically depending on the newData array length.

```js
originalData = [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3},{"id": 4},{"id": 5},{"id": 6}];
newData = ['1','2','3'];
for(var i = 0, j=0; i < originalData.length; i++, j++) {
    originalData[i].color = newData[j];
    if(j == newData.length -1){
        j = -1;
    }
}

console.log(originalData);
```